# Sum up values in Rows in Rectangular Array C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm beginner want to get the Sum each row in 2D Array and print it to the Console and to get the Avg of each column and print it to the Console

I wrote my code to get number of rows and cols from the user and use it to create the Array and ask the user to fill each cell in the array

I stuck in sum up each row I don't get any problem in compiling the file I'm getting this error after finishing fill the numbers:

> at System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormat(IFormatProvider provider, String format, Object[] args)
>      at System.String.Format(IFormatProvider provider, String format, Object[] args)
>      at System.IO.TextWriter.WriteLine(String format, Object arg0, Object arg1)
>      at System.IO.TextWriter.SyncTextWriter.WriteLine(String format, Object arg0, Object arg1)
>      at Program.SumRows(Int32[,] arr, Single rows, Int32 cols)
>      at Program.Main()

this is the code:

```
using System;

struct Program
{
static void Main()
{
    Console.Clear();
    float rows = GetFloatFromUser("Please Enter Number Of Rows: ");
    int cols = GetIntFromUser("Please Enter Number Of Columns: ");
    int[,] recArr = CreatRecArray(rows,cols);
    SumRows(recArr , rows, cols);
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static int GetIntFromUser(string massage)
{
    int result;
    Console.WriteLine(massage);
    result = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    return result;
}
static float GetFloatFromUser(string massage)
{   
    float result;
    Console.WriteLine(massage);
    result = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    return result;
}
static int[,] CreatRecArray(float rows,int cols)
{
int[,] result= new int[(int)rows,cols];
    for (int  i = 0 ; i < rows ; i++)
    {
        for ( int j = 0 ; j < cols ; j++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please Enter Matrix Element {0} , {1} : ",i+1,j+1);
            result[i,j]= int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
    }
return result;
}
static void SumRows(int[,] arr , float rows,int cols)
{
    for (int i = 1 ; i < rows+1 ; i++)
    {
        int result = 0;
        for ( int j = 0 ; j < cols ; j++)
        {
             result += arr[i,j];

        }
        Console.WriteLine("The Sum of row No {0] = {1}",i,result);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `The Sum of row No {0] = {1}` should be `The Sum of row No {0} = {1}`

Comment: Thank You Very Much I just noticed it 
now it gives me Sum
of each row but not the first one !!

Comment: Consider starting your for loop at 0.

Comment: for (int i = 1 ; i < rows+1 ; i++) this will cause IndexOutOfRangeException you should remove the +1

Comment: I did and works all fine and print the Sums
but After few second it gives me this Error **" 
Unhandled Exception: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   at Program.SumRows(Int32[,] arr, Single rows, Int32 cols)
   at Program.Main()"**

Comment: see my previous comment

Comment: @IgorMeszaros yes thats what happend thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        float rows = GetFloatInput("Please Enter Number Of Rows: ");
        int cols = GetIntInput("Please Enter Number Of Columns: ");
        int[,] rectangleArray = CreateRectangleArray(rows, cols);
        SumRows(rectangleArray, rows, cols);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }


    static int[,] CreateRectangleArray(float rows, int cols)
    {
        int[,] result = new int[(int)rows, cols];
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                result[i, j] = GetIntInput($"Please Enter Matrix Element {i+1}, {j+1}");
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    static void SumRows(int[,] arr, float rows, int cols)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            int result = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            {
                result += arr[i, j];
            }
            Console.WriteLine("The Sum of row No {0} = {1}", i, result);
        }
    }

    private static float GetFloatInput(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
        float result = 0;
        while (!float.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to parse your input. Make sure it is numeric. Please try again:");
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static int GetIntInput(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
        int result = 0;
        while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to parse your input. Make sure it is an integer. Please try again:");
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please Explain to me what **TryParse** do?

I get it u want to make sure that the input is an int but how I can use it?

Comment: @OmarMohamed, When facing those question you can either try goodl or write the code, double click the word and press [F1] key https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: The exemple here will give you more information that I can put in 700 char comment.

Comment: @OmarMohamed TryParse is a safer version of Parse. It returns a bool. It returns true if it has succesfully parsed the int/float/whatever. The out parameter contains the result (which you only should use if the bool is true and the parsing is succesfull).

Comment: @OmarMohamed Try for youself what happens when you try to parse a character, like "A", with Parse or TryParse. Parse will give you exceptions where TryParse will not.

Comment: @DragandDrop I got it now it's a way to make sure the input I get from the user is what I'm expecting